# Bootstrap inline-block display

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have a task to build a website using only HTML and BOOTSTRAP but I am getting some problems with side navigation bar (code is attached below). Why the result of my code is not displayed as two inline blocks but blocks are displayed one after another. I use bootstrap predefined class "d-inline-block" but it works only if a paragraph in a second div element is shorter than one line. I want to make two blocks one left, like a navigation block, and one right with some information on the right side.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="d-inline-block">
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item">one</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">two</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">three</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">four</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">five</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="d-inline-block">
                <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
                <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the 
 industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please, point me to my mistake or advice what should be added to code.

(The task is to use only HTML and BOOTSTRAP (I can't add my own CSS code. I can use only predefined BOOTSTRAP classes))

Comment: What do you mean only HTML and Bootstrap, Bootstrap is CSS and Javascript?

Comment: Could you be more clear please, what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: @SusobhanDas Copying substantive code by someone else to their SO question violates their license rights. It's OP's responsibility and prerogative to post their code here as doing so licenses it under CC by-SA, a license with legal ramifications. Please do not make such edits.

Comment: @SusobhanDas: thanks for wanting to edit posts on Stack Overflow. I am an experienced editor and have only just learned about the rule that Tyler refers to, so don't worry about not knowing about it. You can [read more about it here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344484/pasting-fiddle-snippet-into-original-question-as-an-edit).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use bootstrap without creating other CSS rules, I think you should use the bootstrap grid as follows:

```html
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item">one</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">two</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">three</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">four</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">five</li>
        </ul>

      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
        <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
          It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
          desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please remember to paste the code in the question in  the future.

This CSS will make the list show horizontal instead of vertical.

```
.list-group,
.list-group-item{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.d-inline-block{
width:50%;
float:left;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="d-inline-block">
                <ul class="list-group">
                  <li class="list-group-item">one</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item">two</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item">three</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item">four</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item">five</li>
                </ul>

            </div>
            <div class="d-inline-block">
                <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
                <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the 
 industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
            </div>
            <!-- Replace this comment line by "Web Technology 1" homework solution. -->

      </div>

        </body>
</html>
```

The default width of your div's is 100%.  add the following css:

```
.d-inline-block{
width:50%;
float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since CSS isn't an option, in Bootstrap 4 you can use the media object classes to create an object on one side with text next to it that doesn't wrap underneath. The examples they give use images, but you can put text in, too.

```
<div class="media">
  <div> Text</div>
  <div class="media-body">
    Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin. Cras purus odio, vestibulum in vulputate at, tempus viverra turpis. Fusce condimentum nunc ac nisi vulputate fringilla. Donec lacinia congue felis in faucibus.
  </div>
</div>
```

Source: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/media-object/

Bootstrap 3 has similar media classes.

```
  <div class="media">
    <div class="media-left">
        LEFT
    </div>
    <div class="media-body">
     This text will wrap without going underneath the media-left div
    </div>
  </div>
```

Source: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#media